# What is context in Sonata Block Bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

What does the context means inside the configurations of the Sonata Block Bundle? What is for?

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
```

Comment: I wish there was more documentation on the main site.... tststs, such a powerfull API and so little info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, a context is used to group a set of blocks. So you can have block related to a CMS context, or to the admin.

So an admin block will be never used in the CMS context.

Comment: You really wanted the Necromancer badge, hehehe... (just kidding). Thank you :) Just some doubts: you have only those two contexts, or there are more? Can I define custom contexts?

Comment: Just started to reply to question on stackoverflow ... You can have your own context, just use one in the configuration. The cms which as been renamed to sonata_page_bundle is used in the PageBundle. But you can create your own PageBundle like with your own context.